# XMLTable without using namespaces in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to extract xml values using XMLTable in PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE
xdata XMLType := XMLType(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <stusMsg xmlns="http://www.my.namespace.com/src">
            <messageHeader>
              <sourceSystem>PFS</sourceSystem>
              <originatingSystem>MRTI HKH</originatingSystem>
            </messageHeader>
            <messageDetail>
            <TradeRef>1033796</TradeRef>
            <TradeRefType>Ticket</TradeRefType>
            <Company>MY_CMPY</Company>
            <TradeGREF></TradeGREF>
            <TradeType>TRD</TradeType>
            <PriorityType>CRS</PriorityType>
            <Priority>1</Priority>
            </messageDetail>
            </stusMsg>');

CURSOR get_data(x XMLType) IS
SELECT * 
FROM XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.my.namespace.com/src'),
   '/stusMsg/messageDetail'
   passing x
           COLUMNS 
           TradeRef      VARCHAR2(30)    PATH 'TradeRef',
           TradeRefType  VARCHAR2(30)    PATH 'TradeRefType');
BEGIN

FOR rec IN get_data(xdata) LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(rec.TradeRef);
  dbms_output.put_line(rec.TradeRefType);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If I don't use `xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.my.namespace.com/src')` in `XMLTABLE` and namespace is present in the xml (`xdata`) , then the values are not being extracted.

Is there a way to tell `XMLTABLE` to ignore the namespace? so that program don't depend on `xmlnamespaces`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to ignore the namespaces, if there is only a default namespace, you can remove the `xmlns` attribute from the document root:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_dom DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
  xdata XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <stusMsg xmlns="http://www.my.namespace.com/src">
    <messageHeader>
      <sourceSystem>PFS</sourceSystem>
      <originatingSystem>MRTI HKH</originatingSystem>
    </messageHeader>
    <messageDetail>
    <TradeRef>1033796</TradeRef>
    <TradeRefType>Ticket</TradeRefType>
    <Company>MY_CMPY</Company>
    <TradeGREF></TradeGREF>
    <TradeType>TRD</TradeType>
    <PriorityType>CRS</PriorityType>
    <Priority>1</Priority>
    </messageDetail>
    </stusMsg>');
  CURSOR get_data(x XMLType) IS
    SELECT * 
    FROM XMLTABLE(
           '/stusMsg/messageDetail'
           passing x
           COLUMNS 
             TradeRef      VARCHAR2(30)    PATH 'TradeRef',
             TradeRefType  VARCHAR2(30)    PATH 'TradeRefType'
         );
BEGIN
  v_dom  := DBMS_XMLDOM.NEWDOMDOCUMENT(xdata);
  DBMS_XMLDOM.REMOVEATTRIBUTE(
    DBMS_XMLDOM.GETDOCUMENTELEMENT(v_dom),
    'xmlns'
  );
  xdata := DBMS_XMLDOM.GETXMLTYPE(v_dom);
  
  FOR rec IN get_data(xdata) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.TradeRef);
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.TradeRefType);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 1033796
> Ticket
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ef8b9f3da150a02ca6ae379cd649f462)*

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to honour the namespaces in the XML document you can wildcard all of the node references:

```
SELECT * 
FROM XMLTABLE(
   '/*:stusMsg/*:messageDetail'
   passing x
           COLUMNS 
           TradeRef      VARCHAR2(30)    PATH '*:TradeRef',
           TradeRefType  VARCHAR2(30)    PATH '*:TradeRefType');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32f5e4018dedabfebb6e0493dc6de4f5)

But that seems less than ideal; I'd use them properly if you can.

Comment: Thankyou, both the answers works but I have to accept only one